# How can I disable multitouch gestures on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gesture, multi-touch, ubuntu-22.04, gnome-shell-extensions

I was using a GNOME extension to disable multitouch gestures on ubuntu 20.04 but it doesn't work with ubuntu 22.04

Does anybody know how to disable this on **Ubuntu 22.04**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this extension that works to me:

```
wget "https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/disable-gestures-2021verycrazydog.gmail.com.v4.shell-extension.zip"

gnome-extensions install disable-gestures-2021verycrazydog.gmail.com.v4.shell-extension.zip

reboot
```